# How to call PInvoke OpenFile from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

In a full trust, OOB app, I need to be able to open a file (such as a PDF or tiff) through PInvoke.

The PInvoke.net site gives this as the signature:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
static extern int OpenFile([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName, out OFSTRUCT lpReOpenBuff, OpenFileStyle uStyle);
```

However, when I drop this into a test Silverlight App, VS flags the OFStruct as "Cannot resolve symbol"

OpenFileStyle also gets flagged the same way.

How do I modify the signature so it can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I get it now.  OFStruct is a "User Defined Type" which needs to be defined in the project in which the PInvoke call is being used.

On the PInvoke.net site, it gives the C# code for the struct.  So I copied and pasted into the app.  Then the Signature found it and I was able to use the PInvoke.

The same applied to the OpenFileStyle enum.

Greg